# Oracle SP and Trigger only run Successfully once

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I have a weird need to write a trigger and/or SP that will delete all the rows in a table if the databases notices 3 failed logins. Oddly, when i run this, the triger fires every time, and so does the SP, but, the SP  only deletes the records the first time I fail the login 3 times. So, if i fail the login 3 times, the trigger calls the sp and it deletes the records, but if i add another record to the table, and fail the login again, it does not delete the record unless i recompile the SP and the run another failed login.

currently I have this as a trigger

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER TRIG_Failed_Login
after servererror on database

BEGIN
      If (ORA_IS_SERVERERROR(1017)) Then       
          insert into ERRORTRAP (errormessage, message_timestamp) VALUES ('Failed Login - 1017', current_timestamp);      
          commit;
          BEGIN
            sp_trucate_keystore();
          END;  
      END IF;    
End;
```

and this as an SP:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE sp_Trucate_KeyStore is

    RECORD_COUNT NUMBER;
    begin        
         SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RECORD_COUNT FROM ERRORTRAP;   
         BEGIN  
             IF RECORD_COUNT >= 3 THEN 
             INSERT INTO errortrap (errormessage) VALUES ('this is a test');
                 DELETE FROM KEYSTORE;
                 COMMIT;
             END IF; 
         END;
    END;
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: I should notee that the insert in the SP also runs everytime, just the delete from keystore that only runs the first time

Comment: Does DELETE FROM KEYSTORE delete all objects inn the table, including triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are rows getting reinserted into the KEYSTORE table?  Are you inserting those manually via  a separate session, *and* committing prior to your next failed logon attempt?  I was reminded of the comments in this thread: [Oracle stored procedure needs recompilation to fetch table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700276/oracle-stored-procedure-needs-recompilation-to-fetch-table-data)